# Commit and Rollback a DML statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, commit, rollback, dml

I am trying to update a simple statement.

What I want :

- if it is `true` then => **committed** implicitly (using any subprogram);
- if it is `false` => it should **rollback** implicitly (using any subprogram).

**Example**:

```
Update empcp set sal = sal +1000 where empid = 1;
```

This should be **committed** if it is `true` else **rollback**;

Comment: What do you mean with "it is true"? Say you run your update, you get "3 rows updated", how do you decide whether you need to commit or not?

Comment: IF it is untrue no change will be made to DB as the update statement will not update any row. So do a commit after the statement.

Comment: Hi Aleksej  "is it true?" means if empid exist commit should be completed  through any procedure  or trigger( but in trigger it is not possible to Commit or rollback as it works along with DML statement we can use pragma autonomous_transaction)

Comment: loannis Barakos you are right if it is untrue there will not be any change in the DB .But in perspective of a condition where I do not want to increase sal more then 10% For example:update empcp set sal = sal*10/100 where empid = &empid .then if sal > 500 it sholud be rollback otherwise it should commit . here I don't know empid  so I want to create a general subprogram  which commit  for favorable condition and rollback  for unfavorable condition .I hope I made it clear Thanks for response .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're working with PL/SQL, you can use `sql%rowcount` to see if the latest DML statement has had an impact on any row.

```
if sql%rowcount > 0 then commit; else rollback; end if;
```

Keep in mind that you must place this bit of code right after your DML statement in order for `sql%rowcount` to yield the related number of affected rows.
More about the `rownum` pseudocolumn [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm).